# Using Xpath to return multiple elements value

Tags: php, xpath

I have a result from a curl request from a page like this:

```
$result =

<div class="c-wrapper">
  <a href="link-to-a-page.php">
    <div class="c-content-img">
     <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div class="c-link-data">
     <div class="c-link-data-title">
     <h4>TITLE</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
  </a>
<div>

<div class="c-wrapper">
    <div class="c-content-img">
     <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div class="c-link-data">
     <div class="c-link-data-title">
     <h4>TITLE 2</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Now I have to count how many c-wrapper is present:

I use correctly this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$divs = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'c-wrapper')]");

echo $divs-length; //<--- printed: 2
```

Then I have to print all titles:

I use correctly this:

```
$titles = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'c-link-data-title')]/h4");

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title->textContent . "<br>";
}
```

Now the part I don't know: In the first div is present a link, in the second one no link. I'd like to edit my print of titles like this:

```
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    if ( $link_extracted !="" ) 
    echo "<a href='" . $link_extracted . "'>" . $title->textContent . "</a><br>";
    else
    echo $title->textContent . "<br>";
}
```

How can I edit `$titles = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'c-link-data-title')]/h4");` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing this in separate stages, the code finds the c-wrapper elements and then further uses XPath to find the various parts you want inside that particular element, so in

```
$link_extracted = $xpath->evaluate("a/@href", $div)[0];
```

it is looking for an `<a>` element relative to the `$div` element.  Using `[0]` as you want only the first one.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$divs = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'c-wrapper')]");

echo $divs->length;

foreach ( $divs as $div ) {
    $link_extracted = $xpath->evaluate("a/@href", $div)[0];
    $title = $xpath->evaluate("descendant::div[contains(@class, 'c-link-data-title')]/h4/text()"
        , $div)[0];
    if ( !empty($link_extracted->nodeValue) )  {
        echo "<a href='" . $link_extracted->nodeValue . "'>" . $title->textContent . "</a><br>";
    }
    else    {
        echo $title->textContent . "<br>";
    }
}
```

which for your test HTML gives...

```
2<a href='link-to-a-page.php'>TITLE</a><br>TITLE 2<br>
```